# Django South - Any way to detect if south migration needs to be done?

Tags: django, dvcs, django-south

Say you are developing on a Django project with a few people using (for example) git. When you do `git pull` you might get some South migrations, however, you might not notice (for some reason). Then when you go on developing, you might run into python exceptions because you didn't do the migrations. Now sometimes it can be some time before you find out you forgot this, which is pretty annoying.

So therefor I was thinking, can't South detect that you haven't done all the migrations and just throw an exception if so?

I imagen this could be a setting which you could turn off if you want to keep developing without doing the migration.

Comment: I actually found an article that describes how to programatically detect if south has migrations to run (http://rochacbruno.com.br/programatically-check-if-you-south-have-migrations-to-run/). I might convert this into middleware that I'll add in my development settings. I'll answer my own question if I manage to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made some middleware which does what I want. When you do a request it checks which migrations you haven't applied yet and raises an exception. Be sure to use this middleware only in development!

You can also find the source on https://gist.github.com/gitaarik/5974176

```
from south import migration
from south.models import MigrationHistory


class SouthUnranMigrationCheck(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        '''
        Checks if you ran all South migrations. If not, it will throw an
        exception (DidNotApplyAllMigrations).
        '''

        unapplied_migrations = self.unapplied_migrations()

        if len(unapplied_migrations) > 0:

            message = u'You haven\'t run the following migrations: {}'.format(
                u''.join(
                    [u'\n  "{}" in app "{}".'.format(name, app)
                    for name, app in unapplied_migrations]
                )
            )

            raise DidNotApplyAllMigrations(message)

    def unapplied_migrations(self):
        '''
        Returns a list of tuples of unapplied migrations. The tuples consist of
        a migration name and an app label.
        '''

        applied_migrations = self.applied_migrations()
        unapplied_migrations = []

        for app_migration_files in migration.all_migrations():

            for migration_file in app_migration_files:

                app_label = migration_file.app_label()
                migration_name = migration_file.name()

                if migration_name not in applied_migrations[app_label]:
                    unapplied_migrations.append((migration_name, app_label))

        return unapplied_migrations

    def applied_migrations(self):
        '''
        Returns a dictionary with the app name in the key, and a list of
        migrations in the value.
        '''

        applied_migrations = {}

        for applied_migration in MigrationHistory.objects.all():

            if applied_migration.app_name not in applied_migrations:
                applied_migrations[applied_migration.app_name] = []

            applied_migrations[applied_migration.app_name].append(
                applied_migration.migration)

        return applied_migrations


class DidNotApplyAllMigrations(Exception):
    '''
    Exception that indicates that you havent run all migrations.
    '''
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

ok, that's my way.

I have a app `south_test` with 3 migrations, that's the ´python manage.py migrate --list´ shows:

```
south_test
  (*) 0001_initial
  (*) 0002_auto__add_person
  ( ) 0003_auto__add_field_person_age
```

That is (not too) magic code:

```
from south.models import MigrationHistory
from south.migration import Migrations

all_migrations = Migrations('south_test')
applied_migrations = MigrationHistory.objects.filter(app_name='south_test')

not_applied = list(set(all_migrations) - set([migration.get_migration() for migration in applied_migrations]))
```

Now you have `not_applied` migrations.
Maybe there are some details with ghost migrations.

See the `migrate` command of south for details.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks lalo. Ultimately I created my own middleware which solves my issue. Check my answer.